# Alternative to bash (awk command) with python

Tags: python, bash

Context : I run calculations on a program that gives me result files.
On these result files (extension .h5), I can apply a python code (I cannot change this python code) such that it gives me a square matrix :

```
oneptdm.py resultfile.h5
```

gives me for example :

```
1   2  3  4
5   6  7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
points groups
1
2
3
...
```

in a file called oneptdm.dat

I want to grep the diagonal of this matrix. Usually I use simply bash:

```
awk '{ for (i=0; i<=NF; i++) if (NR >= 1 && NR == i) print i,$(i) }' oneptdm.dat > diagonal.dat
```

But for x reason, I have to do it with python now. How can I do that ?
I can of course use "subprocess" to use awk again but I would like to know if there is an alternative way to do that with a python script, version 2.6. 
The result should be :

```
(line)  (diagonal element)
1       1
2       6
3       11
4       16
```

Comment: Note that your slightly confusing looking awk script could be written as `awk '{ print NR, $NR }' file`

Comment: That's an Awk script, not a Bash script (though the redirection has to be handled by a shell, of course).

Comment: @tripleee Sure, you are right, but don't forget that `awk` can do io on it's own. Like `awk '{print "foo" > bar}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. It does assume that the file begins with a square matrix, and that assumption is used to limit the number of lines read from the file.

```
with open('oneptdm.dat') as f:
    line = next(f).split()
    for i in range(len(line)):
        print('{0}\t{1}'.format(i+1, line[i]))
        try:
            line = next(f).split()
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

Output for your sample file:

```
1   1
2   6
3   11
4   16
```

Comment: I have an error "print('{}\t{}'.format(i+1, line[i])) ValueError: zero length field name in format" when using your code. I have python 2.6.6 implemented in the machine I use, I don't know if it is the reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
with open('oneptdm.dat') as f:
    for i, l in enumerate(f):
        print '%d\t%s' % (i + 1, l.split()[i])
```

Comment: I'd use `enumerate` rather than manually updating `i` in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @AlexeiShestakov: unfortunately your otherwise correct answer has been invalidated by an update to the input file format. Better fix it before it attracts downvotes.

Comment: It works, but with an additional error : print('%d\t%s' % (i, l.split()[i-1])) IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: @B_runo: yes, that's because you changed the file format after this answer was posted, so this code doesn't handle additional lines in the file. You probably shouldn't accept the answer if it doesn't work.